# How to declare a POST request with different read / write representation of sub entities in OpenAPI?

Tags: rest, post, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

In an POST request I want reference to other objects per id but in the response I want the whole object.

**Song POST Request:**

```
{
  "title": "Never Gonna Give You Up",
  "genre": 4,
  "singer": 10
}
```

**Song POST Response:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Never Gonna Give You Up",
  "genre": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Dance Pop"
  },
  "singer": {
    "id": 10
    "firstName": "Rick",
    "lastName": "Astley"
  }
}
```

I can achieve this with separate schema definitions for request and response but this is difficult for OpenAPI code generation for java.

Is there another way for specifying in OpenAPI or what is the general practice for referencing to other objects in POST requests?